# How to fix red warning of `import com.r3.testing.DistributeTestsBy` of build.gradle when using IDEA?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, corda

I imported [corda project](https://github.com/corda/corda) using IDEA and VCS => get from version control.
And build.gradle files not work correctly displaying red warnings like this.
[image]

I guess I need some library import or IDEA setting.
How to fix these red warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reimport gradle project.
[image]

Comment: Is right side gradle tab a plugin ?? There isn't that icon.

Comment: Try to right-click on `build.gradle` and click on `Import Gradle Project`